# Format grep Output in Columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, printf

I have a large log file, from which I need to extract some specific data, to be more precise, the values of distinct fields that appear repeatedly, i.e. I need to get some information from many CDRs, such as call type, origination number, etc.

The original text formatting is as per below:

```
Reason Code:"XXX",  Result Code:XXX, Desc: "XXX"
..
A_NUMBER.ADDRESS = XXX
..
```

Using egrep I have managed to get the required lines, which appear to be like:

```
 Reason Code:"XXX",  Result Code:XXX, Desc: "XXX"
 RECORD_IDENTIFICATION.FILE_ID: XXX
 A_NUMBER.ADDRESS = XXX
 Call is from XXXX, VDATE=XXXX.
```

but I am not being able to format them in a tabular style, grouped by Reason, File_ID, A_Num and Call Date, acting as column heads,
like

```
Reason Code | File_ID | A_Number | Date 
  xxxx | xxxx | xxxx | xxxx |
```

I am not really interested in the appearance, I just want the elements to be consecutive, in order to belong to the same call.

I have messed with different variants of awk, sed and printf, but nothing seems to work.

I have tried to put the total characters value as a parameter in printf

```
printf "%-205s\n" $(grep -E 'Reason Code|RECORD_IDENTIFICATION.FILE_ID|A_NUMBER.ADDRESS|Call is from' file.err)
```

or

```
printf "%-65s | %-65s |  %-65s | %-65s" $(grep -E 'Reason Code|RECORD_IDENTIFICATION.FILE_ID|A_NUMBER.ADDRESS' file.err | awk 'FS = "\n" {print $1}')
```

but the values in output are scrambled and unusable.

In my opinion the solution may lay in some sort of loop, which awk seems to support, but I am not being able to sort it out.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: [Edit] your question to show us a minimal example of your sample input and the corresponding desired output. If you've made an attempt, then show us that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform the output of your `grep` command with `sed` :

```
sed 'N;N;N;s/Reason Code:"\([^"]*\).*FILE_ID: \([^\n]*\).*A_NUMBER.ADDRESS = \([^\n]*\).*VDATE=\([^.]*\).*/\1 \2 \3 \4/'
```

```
$ echo ''' Reason Code:"XXX",  Result Code:XXX, Desc: "XXX"
 RECORD_IDENTIFICATION.FILE_ID: XXX
 A_NUMBER.ADDRESS = XXX
 Call is from XXXX, VDATE=XXXX.''' | sed 'N;N;N;s/Reason Code:"\([^"]*\).*FILE_ID: \([^\n]*\).*A_NUMBER.ADDRESS = \([^\n]*\).*VDATE=\([^.]*\).*/\1 \2 \3 \4/'
 XXX XXX XXX XXXX
```

However, it would be best to avoid using `grep` and let `sed` also do the filtering. I can't propose such a solution since you didn't post the format of your unfiltered data.

Comment: thank you for the solution. It does what I was searching for, and more, as it gives only the values, without additional text. However I am facing an issue that I am not being able to solve. The output for Row 1 and 2 are aligned, meanwhile the results for row 3 and 4 are each in a new row below. Do you have any idea why might this happen?

Comment: Yes, right :)
This is the last version of your code that I am using, as I slightly modified it to include the respective value of "Call is from":
`code` sed 'N;N;N;s/Reason Code:"\([^"]*\).*RECORD_IDENTIFICATION.FILE_ID: \([^\n]*\).*A_NUMBER.ADDRESS = \([^\n]*\).*Call is from \([^,]*\).*/\1 \2 \3 \4/'

Comment: That looks good to me, there shouldn't be any linefeed matched by the grouped patterns... Could you maybe reproduce the problem with some sample data in an [ideone](https://ideone.com/) snippet?

Comment: When I add a single block via echo, the output is fine (please check: https://ideone.com/OyM4Oi)  meanwhile when I send the output to a .txt file, occurs the problem that I described

Comment: It's not the output redirection, [this snippet](https://ideone.com/djldvI) also redirects the result to a file and the file's content contains no linefeed. It could maybe be extra characters (`\r` that would be grouped and then displayed as a linefeed?) or environment dependant.

Comment: You are right. It may be due to the fact that the original file was produced in a HP UX server. I have had compatibility issues with these files in Windows environments, but since I was performing the above actions in a Linux server, I thought that there would not be a problem.